# Arial in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, font-face, chromium

I have a problem with Arial (maybe other fonts too) in Chrome/Chromium.
It looks good when I use font-family: Arial;
But when I include Arial font-file via @font-face it looks different!
Why could it be? What can I do to make them look the same? Where exactly Chrome takes its fonts?
Here is my css

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My Arial';
    src: url(Arial.ttf) format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

body#native {
    font-family: Arial;
}

body#fontface {
    font-family: 'My Arial';
}
```

Here is the rendered text:

[image: Here is the pic].

Sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

Comment: @noHDD Having this issue on both Debian Squeeze and Arch Linux

Comment: I’m guessing it’s a hinting different between the system OpenType file (.otf) and the font-face included Truetype file (.ttf). Can you double-check what format the system file is in?

Comment: @Sparky672 My sample is not the best, but you still can see problem. Actually this problem becomes more obvious with numbers and cyrillic. If you want, I can make another example.

Comment: @Robin The only arial fonts were found by `find / -iname "*arial*"` are truetype. And `fc-match -v Arial | grep fontformat` output is  fontformat: "TrueType"(s)

Comment: I see the slight difference.  However, my point:  **is the large amount of effort worth the small end result?**  Every browser is going to handle fonts slightly different and it also depends on operating system and its installed fonts.  The various combinations of fonts, browsers, operating systems, etc. is practically infinite.

Comment: I guess that Chrome is using the systems built in text renderer, so it might be impossible to control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use @font-face a lot, and there's always a difference in how different browsers render it. With some fonts it gets really ugly, in your particular case, I'd say difference is insignificant, and everything else just as Sparky672 already commented.

If you absolutely must have pixel-precise identical rendering on all systems, maybe some javascript based solution may help, check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/692994/525445

Again, if this was my site on your screenshots, I'd be perfectly happy with how it looks.

It's just the nature of the web that not everyone will see the identical thing, there are different monitors with different color settings, different resolutions, some people zoom in the text etc.

Just to mention the option, you can detect Chrome with JavaScript and then apply some specific CSS to tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Arial file you're including with @font-face the same exact file from your system or did you get it from somewhere else? There could be difference in the files that's causing the difference. If not, then as @Sparky672 said in his last comment, there's not much you can do, it's just a browser rendering issue.

Also, out of curiosity, why are you including Arial with @font-face, since it's available on virtually every system?

Comment: I used Arial file from my system, however I tried files downloaded from the Internet and got the same result. Arial is not available on every system, it was not on Debian or Arch when I installed them.

Comment: Then it's definitely an a difference somehow in the rendering of a native font versus the font with @font-face.