# Font Arial with different result in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, mozilla

I've problem with displaying font in different browser. In my CSS style, I declare `font-family: Arial !important;` and `font-weight:normal;` to my `body`. When I open my site with mozilla firefox and chrome, the font in mozilla seems thicker than chrome.

[image]

I also using `reset.css` but it's not making any different. Another browser like ie and opera give the same result as chrome.

Anyone knows how to force the font in each browser became the same with each other?

Comment: This question has been asked many times in different versions. The general answer can be summarized “That’s life.”

Answer (score 2):

Please don't quote me on this but I remember reading something about Chrome rendering text a little differently to the conventional way other CSS engines do it. So there's a chance you're not doing anything wrong and it's just the browser.

Please ensure that DirectWrite is switched on. (It should be if your Chrome is up to date)

You can do that by going to chrome://flags and having a look at the "DirectWrite" row.

You've got to remember that the way text looks is more dependant on the browser's rendering capability - More so than the CSS. I know it sounds odd, but you're not the only one:

[The same font looks different in Chrome vs. Firefox, IE and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401235/the-same-font-looks-different-in-chrome-vs-firefox-ie-and-safari)

[Arial in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213691/arial-in-chrome)

[Fonts looks different in Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698564/fonts-looks-different-in-firefox-and-chrome)

Sorry, I know it doesn't directly answer your query, but I just wanted to let you know that it's probably more of a browser issue than a CSS one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is because Mozilla and Chrome using diferrent CSS engine, so I can check that both are using same letter and the different is really minimum, is just because those are different web browsers, they never will be exactly equal at least not with the same instructions.

Comment: It seems not only the font is different, I just notice that my layout is also different. I declare `<input type="text" style="width:120px;" />` but it looks like in chrome display is more longer than mozilla.
Do you have any suggestion for me to solve this problem? Please..

Comment: Like I said in the post, there are nothing that you can do, because this is a browser issue, I mean, you can try to force similarities, but this will be more dangerous, I'm sorry.